# Is There Any Advantage Of Using "Chris Lea Redis PPA" Vs Installing From Ubuntu Repository

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Two advantages that I saw was redis version and security, but, for those who know redis better are there any advantages?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage you get with a PPA is that as soon as a software update is pushed, you get it.

As for security, I wouldn't say it is an advantage of a PPA per se, especially if you're a beginner. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for) handles the subject very well.